# Crossdomain jQuery.ajax sometimes doesn't work in firefox 8 but works in Chrome/IE

Tags: ajax, firefox, jquery

I have this script that queries my Ruby on Rails application (located on a remote domain) using jQuery 1.7.1. The script works fine in Chrome and even in IE9, but not in Firefox.

Here is the script:

```
Informer= {
  getData: function(args)
  {     
    $.ajax({
      dataType: 'jsonp',            
      data: args,
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/informer.js',
      beforeSend: function () {
        alert("beforeSend");
      },
      error: function () {
        alert("error");
      },
      success: function (data) {      
        alert("success");
      },
      complete: function(){
        alert("complete");
      } 
    });
  }
}
```

I call it like this

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  Informer.getData(someArgs);
});
```

So in chrome I get 3 alerts, while in firefox I only get "beforeSend". I also don't see any requests in firebug.

It definitely has something to do with the URL. I changed it to http://jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/ and it worked. 
But I still have 2 why's:

**upd**

In short, here's what I have so far:

1. It didn't work for me yesterday at all (3 hours wasted, sigh) and it does today.
2. It always works in Chrome and IE
3. The request is not shown in Firebug
4. When the script fails (meaning, I only get the beforeSend alert), my app's log doesn't get updated (I assume, FF doesn't send the request)
5. Tried using jquery-jsonp with no result
6. **10 of 11 users with FF8 reported that the script worked.**

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/bassneck/23pNx/5/) the test script for those who are interrested (if any)

Comment: Make sure that URL exists. Are you sure you want to do the AJAX call to another JS file?

Comment: Hey, Jemaclus. As I said, the script works perfectly fine in Chrome, so the URL exists for sure. The informer.js is not a file actually. It's a ruby on rails action that returns JSONP.

Comment: Just for fun I put together this: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/NKgyM/ sample.  Now my question is WHY does yours error (alert error) on ANY browser unless you have an error on the url you are using.

Comment: Gotcha. That is an interesting bug. It SHOULD trigger the error handler... I tried replacing the URL with something I know is valid (google.com), and it worked fine. Perhaps it has something to do with the localhost and port? Good bug find...

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss, strange thing - your example works fine in both Chrome and FF.

Comment: @Jemaclus, nope. I've tried pointing it to production with no result.

Comment: note my example uses valid javascript where jslint shows an error on yours with the missing semi-colon on the ajax function.

Comment: I'm using your example now, and, actually, jslint shows 3 errors it it :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to make yours valid:(I inserted the howdy part for your ... not knowing what you had  there and to bogus args) can you test this:

```
Informer = {
    getData: function(args) {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            data: args,
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/informer.js',
            beforeSend: function() {
               alert("beforeSend");
             },
            error: function() {
                 alert("error");
            },
            success: function(data) {
                 alert("success");
         },
            complete: function() {
                 alert("complete");
        }
        });
    },
    howdy: {}
};
var someArgs = {
    hi: "me"
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    Informer.getData(someArgs);
});
```

EDIT: Fixed parameter issue in: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/NKgyM/

and set it to echo the returned value.

Comment: The same thing. Works in Chrome, fails in FF :(

Comment: hmm I wonder if we comment out the alert in beforesend part if that would produce the error alert then.  Sorry I do not have the exact browser to test in.